# Connect SAP PI to Salesforce via OAuth and REST API - How get a everlasting Bearer Token

Tags: apexrest, sap

I am fairly new to REST API and the OAuth stuff ... so my question might be somewhat silly. However...

We want to call a Salesforce REST API that's coded in an APEX class from SAP PI. A proof of concept is already working perfectly... but: Every now and then the Bearer token expires. I went through the documentation and some other documents but I didn't find a way to obtain a Bearer token that does not expire.
The guys dealing with the SAP PI interface say that they are not able to obtain a fresh Bearer token before they issue a REST call toward Salesforce. Since I am not an SAP professional, I do not know if it is true or not.
So I do have three questions:

1. Is there a way to obtain a Bearer token from Salesforce that will not expire so the guys from SAP PI can store that Bearer token?
2. Is there a better authorization method so that we can connect SAP PI with Salesforce in a way that we do not need to login again every now and then?
3. Is there someone who knows an easy way to obtain a new Bearer token in SAP PI?

Kindly appreciate any answer.

Comment: Have you tried asking on SAP forums? SAP PI is [capable](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/06/18/integrate-sap-pi7.4-with-sfdcoauth2.0/) of doing oAuth via an adapter or you can hand-code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Derek's answer, the token will definitely expire one way or another unless you refresh it. I know when we have integrated other web applications with Salesforce in the past we have used a Connected App in conjunction with a refresh token, you basically make a call with the refresh token (amongst other things) and Salesforce will return an updated access token, giving the illusion of a everlasting token. This does require you to store the refresh token securely though.

You *could* use SFDX to retrieve the access token as SFDX will take care of refreshing the access token. This would however mean authorising an org with SFDX on your integration server and your integration being able to use it.

but I suspect the real best practice would be to go down the route of [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) in this case since "the SAP PI interface say that they are not able to obtain a fresh Bearer token before they issue a REST call".

Answer (score 2):

The "Bearer token" you're talking about here is what Salesforce calls an *access token*.

There is no way to guarantee that an access token doesn't expire, no matter how you authenticate. It's functionally equivalent to a session, and the maximum session timeout that Salesforce currently allows is 24 hours.

The timeout can be controlled at 3 levels. In order of priority (high -> low), they are:

- Through the connected app
- Through the user detail page
- Through an org-wide default

If you're making calls to Salesforce, using an access token, with sufficient frequency, then the access token can functionally live forever. At minimum, you'd need to make a single request after the access token is half-way to expiring to cause the session timeout to be reset. 3 requests made at equal intervals spread throughout the timeout (so if your timeout was 1 hour, you'd make 1 request every 20 minutes) should guarantee the session stays alive too.

Salesforce doesn't start checking for activity in a session until the last half of the configured timeout has elapsed.

Probably the simplest authentication approach you can use is to just always ask for a new token from the `/services/oauth/token` endpoint. If the current access token is still valid, you'll get the current access token back. If the current access token has expired, you'll get a new access token back.

I'm afraid I don't know about the capabilities of SAP PI either, so I can't comment on whether or not chaining two calls together (one to make sure you have a valid access token, the other to actually make the request) is possible, but I'd have a hard time believing something resembling that isn't possible in any modern software solution.